# Understanding Go Pointers

Tags: pointers, go

I expect this code to produce 4 addresses, 2 for each node, thus, having 2 identical addresses, and then another set of 2 identical addresses:

```
type node struct {
    identifier string
    parent     *node
    children   []*node
    root       int
}

func visitNodes(root *node) {   
    for i := 0; i < len(root.children); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Visiting node %s\n", &root.children[i])
        printNodeAddress(root.children[i])
    }
}

func printNodeAddress(node *node) {
    fmt.Println(&node)
}


func main() {
    root := new(node)
    node1 := new(node)
    node2 := new(node)

    root.children = append(root.children, node1)
    root.children = append(root.children, node2)

    visitNodes(root)
}
```

Produces:

```
Visiting node  %!s(**main.node=0x10500170)
0x10500180
Visiting node  %!s(**main.node=0x10500174)
0x10500190
```

While I *expect* it to produce something like this:

```
Visiting node  %!s(**main.node=0x10500170)
0x10500170
Visiting node  %!s(**main.node=0x10500174)
0x10500174
```

Am I misunderstanding the fundamentals of go pointers, or is different when dealing with slices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're taking the address of a pointer:

```
func printNodeAddress(node *node) {
    fmt.Println(&node) // there's now a second layer of indirection in here. a **node
}
```

When really what you're trying to see is the pointer's memory address. You should change your `Printf` to this:

```
fmt.Printf("Visiting node %p\n", root.children[i])
```

And your `printNodeAddress` function to this:

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", node)
```

Then you'll get this:

```
Visiting node 0x1052f2c0
0x1052f2c0
Visiting node 0x1052f2e0
0x1052f2e0
```

Comment: Agreed.  Here is the playground link I was going to include in my answer: http://play.golang.org/p/rs57O_9E1u